# Why the isochrone is changing its shape?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, route, isochrone

I am doing some isochrones using the OSM route plugin in QGIS, but if I am keeping my working space open for a few of hours, the shape of the isochrones is changing. I guess that from the RecursiveGrid mode, turns into TIN mode without me changing any setting. Does somebody know what is the reason behind this?